# C++ ZeroMQ Single Application with both REQ and REP sockets

Tags: python, c++, sockets, zeromq

I am trying to write an application that uses ZeroMQ to recieve messages from clients.  I receive the message from the client in the main loop, and need to send an update to a second socket (general idea is to establish a 'change feed' on objects in the database the application is built on).

Receiving the message works fine, and both sockets are connected without issue.  However, sending the request on the outbound port simply hangs, and the test server meant to receive the message does not receive anything.

Is it possible to use both a REQ and REP socket within the same application?

For reference, the main application is C++ and the test server and test client communicating with it are written in Python.  They are all running on Ubuntu 14.40.  Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

And this is what happens when you forget to call connect() on the socket...